# Get equation for graphic

Tags: mathematica

Is it possible to get the equation of a graphic you have drawn using the drawing tools in Mathematica?
I want to do this because I drew something using the drawing tools, and now I want to programmely edit it to add a point at a specific coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** possible to get the code that generates the graphics you added using the drawing tools.

For example, here's a quadratic where I've used the drawing tools to add in arrows to the x-intercepts:

```
Plot[x^2 - 4, {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image: quadratic]

After the graphics type `// InputForm` to see the code that makes the graphics. In this case I've also used `/. Line[x_] -> Line` to suppress all of the points that make up the plot:
[image]

The highlighted code is that which was added by the drawing tools. It can be simplified (e.g., remove the `EdgeForm` commands and replacing the `Inset` `Cell` with just a plain `Text` command) when you add it back to your original `Plot`, which can be done with an [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Epilog.html) (or a [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Prolog.html)) or by using [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html).